# how to write a function to fold certain patterns

Tags: vim, folding

Hello I am coding R and would like to be able to fold function
In R I code function like this:

```
myFnName <- function(some, args){
    #some description or not
    some code
}
```

My question is how can I code a function that will fole the function like automatically when hitting some key even inside the function. I know I can set `fdm=manual` but then I have to do it on the 100's of function I have.

```
myFnName <- function(some, args){
+----------------
```

Comment: Did you try `:set foldmethod=indent`?

Comment: sure I did, and it did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "did not work" with `indent`?

Both `syntax` and `indent` work, but your problem may be that both methods don't take comments into account so they don't do anything for your sample (they see only one line so there's nothing to fold).

As soon as you have more than one line of actual code, `za`, `zM`, `zR` and friends work perfectly.

Another method worth trying is `marker`, using `:set foldmarker={,}` allows you to turn:

```
myFnName <- function(some, args){
    #some description or not
    some code
}
```

into:

```
+--  4 lines : myFnName <- function(some, args)--------
```

with a simple `za`.

Anyway, I recommend these two vimcasts if you want more control:

- [How to fold](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/how-to-fold/)
- [Writing a custom fold expression](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/writing-a-custom-fold-expression/)

Comment: Merci Romain! Your `foldmarker` works nicely, that's good enough for me

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's a plugin that does that.

Read the help on how to write a custom folding function for the R filetype: [`:h 'foldexpr'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27foldexpr%27), [`:h fold-expr`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-expr).

Read the in-depth tutorial on custom folding in *Learn Vim Script the Hard Way* by Steve Losh: ["Advanced Folding"](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/49.html).